# Mysql Query taking long time where using variable

Tags: mysql, events

I had an mysql event and runs eery day at 9:45 AM.

```
Begin
 SET @v_ym :=(SELECT extract(year_month from DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)));
 SELECT CAST(@ym AS CHAR);
 select ssaname,extract(year_month from date_sub(sysdate(),interval 1 day)) ym,
        omcr.btscount_ssa(ssaname) btscount,sum(case when duration>30 then duration else 0 end) dur_30 from
        btsoutage.bts_faults 
        where ym=@v_ym  and ssaname is not null
        group by ssaname;
END;
```

in the query [ym is yearmonth and ym is indexed] when i substitute with variable @v_ym it is taking full table scan and the table is locked for further inserts. where as when i given the value directly it is using index and the output is fast.

The table contains more than 10 million records.

Create table is

```
CREATE TABLE `bts_faults` (
  `bts_name` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `make` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occuredtime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `clearedtime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `duration` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `reason` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_type` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tech` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fault_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ssaname` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fault_type` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `remarks` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bts_section` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vendor` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occureddate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `cleareddate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ym` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `USERNAME` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mask` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `mask_cat` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `outage_cat` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `site_category` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `escalated_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `zone` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zone_fault_reason` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zone_fault_remarks` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zone_username` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zone_updatetime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `zone_fault_duration` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fault_category` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remarks_1` varchar(2500) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fault_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UIDX_BTS_FAULTS` (`bts_name`,`occuredtime`),
  KEY `indx_btsfaults_ym` (`ym`),
  KEY `indx_btsfaults_cleareddate` (`cleareddate`),
  KEY `Index_btsfaults_btsname` (`bts_name`),
  KEY `index_btsfaults_ssaname` (`ssaname`),
  KEY `indx_btsfaults_occureddate` (`occureddate`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3807469710 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

The Explain Plan for the 2 type are

[image]

Comment: For non-Indian readers, 1 crore = 10 million.

Comment: Is this really your event code? What is the purpose of doing some SELECT queries every day? I assume you are really storing the result of the SELECT query into some other table. That's the only way it would cause locking.

Comment: If you ask a question about query optimization, please include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <name>` so we can see what columns, indexes, data types you have defined. That will help us to analyze the best solution.

Comment: This is transaction table and trying to create a summary table in order to reduce the direct load on the table

Answer (score 1):

What percentage of the table is in the "current month"?  If that is more than something like 20%, then there is no fix -- a table scan is likely to be faster.  If it is less than 20%, then, as you suspect, @variables may be the villain.  In that case, change the test to be

```
 WHERE ym = CAST(
          extract(year_month from DATE_SUB(SYSDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
                 AS CHAR)
   AND ...
```

Much faster would be to build and maintain a Summary Table with a `PRIMARY KEY` of day and ssaname.  This would have the subtotals for each day.  It would be maintained either as the data is `INSERTed` or each night after midnight.

Then the 9:45 query becomes very fast.  Maybe so fast that you don't even need to do it just once a day, but instead "on-demand".

More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables

I suggest you use `NOW()` instead of `SYSDATE()` -- The former is constant throughout a statement; the latter is not.

`bts_faults` looks like it might be a terabyte in size.  If so, you probably don't want to here ways to make is smaller.

If the Auto_inc value is at 3.8B, yet there are only 10M rows, does this mean that you are purging 'old' data?  Do you want to discuss speeding up the Deletes?  (Start a new Question if you do.)

Comment: still not working with change of now(),
```select ym, ssaname,
        omcr.btscount_ssa(ssaname) btscount,sum(case when duration>30 then duration else 0 end) dur_30 from btsoutage.bts_faults where ym=EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)))group by ym, ssaname;```
It is not using the index created on ym , where as the same query is working fast 
when EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM (DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))) is replaced by 202111
The table contains only 18Million data.

Comment: @srimannarayana - Ah...  I think I see the issue.  I had "varchar = date-constant"  Let's change it to "varchar = char-constant".  I modified my Answer.

Comment: @srimannarayana - Please add the revised `SELECT` and its `EXPLAIN` to your Question.

Comment: The explain paln for 2 queries is added in the question

Comment: @srimannarayana - I don't see the `CAST` being used to get the value.  It seems to be a datatype issue, so I need the CAST.